# I want to know that how can i access my modal form elements in my code behind .Also I want to know how can I apply jquery validator on modal form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I want to know that how can i access my modal form elements in my code behind .Also I want to know how can I apply jquery validator on modal form.

My webform code is as follows

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="HotelReservation.Views.test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
    .modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  background-color: #333333;
  opacity:0.5; 

    }
</style>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../js/customLoginJS.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/StyleSheetLoginPage.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' />
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body style="background-image:url('../images/f_img_132.png')" >


    <div class="form-container" style="background-color: rgba(179, 179, 179,0.9); width: 23%; margin: auto; margin-top: 170px; padding-bottom: 60px; padding-top: 16px; border-radius: 20px; z-index: 100">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"></div>
            <form id="form1" runat="server" style="margin-top: 100px;">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend style="font-family: 'Montserrat'">Login</legend>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control-plaintext" value="email@example.com" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label style="font-family: 'Montserrat'" for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" runat="server" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" />
                        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted-white">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label style="font-family: 'Montserrat'" for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" runat="server" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>

                    <label id="error" runat="server" style="color: red"></label>
                    <br />

                    <button id="Button1" type="submit" runat="server" onserverclick="Button1_ServerClick" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Login</button>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
                    <br />
                   <br />
                    <%--<button type="submit" id="idSignUp" runat="server" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Sign Up</button>--%>
                    <div class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">Sign Up</div>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="modal" id="mymodal">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" >
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title" style="font-family: 'Montserrat'">Register</h4>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder=" Full Name" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="uname" placeholder="User Name" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password1" placeholder="Confirm Password" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Text1" placeholder="City" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Text2" placeholder="Country" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Text3" placeholder="Zipcode" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">

                             <input type="date" class="form-control" value="Enter birthday" name="bday" required="required"/>
                        </div>
                        <br />

                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="submit" runat="server" class="btn btn-warning" onserverclick="Unnamed_ServerClick">Register</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>



        </div>
    </div>
```

My javascript code for jquery validator is something like this:-

```
 <script>
           $(document).ready(function () {
               var $validator = $("#form1").validate({
                   rules: {
                       uname: {
                           required: true,
                           email: true,
                           minlength: 3
                       }
                   }
               })
           });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

My code  behinde part is:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace HotelReservation.Views
{
    public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string uname = exampleInputEmail1.Value;
        }

        protected void Unnamed_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //here i want to access modal elements like the text box etc
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance .Please help.I want a jquery validator and a code behinde access for the modal elements.

Answer (score 1):

Well for making it simple just use ajax for whatever you want to do.Use ajax to access data on server or to set data on modal controls.This will be the simplest.

Comment: arent there  any other way and i am having problem with jquery validator too

Comment: and if using ajax i am getting null values in my data feild

Comment: $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "test.aspx/MyMethod",
                   data: "{ Param1: '" + name+ "',Param2: '" + uname + "'}",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: "json",
                   async: "true",
                   cache: "false",
                   success: function (msg) {
                       // On success                 
                   },
                   Error: function (x, e) {
                       // On Error
                   }
               });

Comment: u have to post your server side webmethod code also

Comment: [WebMethod]
        public static void MyMethod(string Param1, string Param2)
        {
            try
            {
                string p = Param1;
                var x = p;                //Do here server event  
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;

            }
        }

Comment: You said you are getting null values right? and in ajax you passed name and uname for key Param1 and Param2 . Now just use jquery debugger and in inspect element check if those two variable have any value before ajax call or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185434/discussion-between-gourab-konar-and-shubham-saini).